# Socket.io not working with React & Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am created a MERN application which also need real-time communication. For that I am using socket.io as shown below:

index.js (server):

```
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import AuthRoutes from "./routes/AuthRoutes.js";
import MessageRoutes from "./routes/MessageRoutes.js";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth",AuthRoutes);
app.use("/api/message",MessageRoutes);

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Server Started on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
})

const io = new Server(server,{
    cors:{
        origin:'http://localhost:3000'
    }
});

io.on("Connection",(socket)=>{
    console.log("a new user connected!! ",socket);
    socket.on("hello",(data)=>{
        console.log("socket hello invoked: ",data)
    })
})
```

Here is the server on connection is not printing the console log in the terminal. Even on emitting event from frontend, server don't print out the `socket hello invoked` in the terminal.

login.jsx (ReactJS frontend):

```
import {io} from "socket.io-client";

  useEffect(()=>{
    const ioClient = io("http://localhost:3005");
    console.log("emiting!!")
    ioClient.emit("hello","yes")
    console.log("emitted")
  },[])
```

My frontend is on `http://localhost:3000` and my backend is on `http://localhost:3005`. I think my frontend is not making the request properly. I am gone through docs of socket.io but still not able to figure it out why the server is not listening for events from the frontend?

Comment: should it be io.on("Connection") or io.on("connection")?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you create your socket connection with the `ws` protocol ?

```js
import {io} from "socket.io-client";

  useEffect(()=>{
    const ioClient = io("ws://localhost:3005");
    console.log("emiting!!")
    ioClient.emit("hello","yes")
    console.log("emitted")
  },[])
```

on your server I would also write

```
io.on("connection",...
```

instead of

```
io.on("Connection",...
```

let me know!